# html cannot get rid of top margin

Tags: php, html, css, web

My web page is having a top margin.

[image]

I cannot get rid of it. I tried

```
html {
    margin:0px;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your url

Comment: Please upload required HTML and CSS

Comment: Did you inspect the element that has the margin applied in the developer tools computed tab? Maybe ``margin-top`` is explicitly overridden somewhere else, so that another margin takes precedence.

Comment: try using:html {
    margin:0px !important;
} but it will be better if you share some code.

Comment: Are you using a template? Or another css style sheet that overrules yours. If you share your HTML and CSS people might be able to help you.

Comment: sry figured it out i didnt notice, inspect element helped it was the <p> that margin had to be 0,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Call Suitable reset css 
[Reset CSS](http://www.cssreset.com/)

A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline. In case you didn't know, every browser has its own default 'user agent' stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible.

Answer (score 0):

hi lot of css elements have default margin and padding , always use reset css 
add following code in your css

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or refer below link
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/nomargin.shtml